# Pyspark Error when UDF is defined outside function that calls it: Method __getnewargs__([]) does not exist

Tags: pyspark, apache-spark-sql, aws-glue

I've seen several questions about this but I don't seem to understand why I get this error when my UDF is defined outside of the function I'm calling on my dataframe.

```
import sys
from awsglue.transforms import *
from awsglue.utils import getResolvedOptions
from pyspark.context import SparkContext
from awsglue.context import GlueContext
from awsglue.job import Job

from data.utils import PropertiesGetter

glueContext = GlueContext(SparkContext.getOrCreate())

input_source = glueContext.create_dynamic_frame.from_catalog(database = "db_name", table_name = "input")
input_source_df = input_source.toDF()

test_df = PropertiesGetter(glueContext).add_subscription_properties(input_df)
```

Calling PropertiesGetter's `add_subscription_properties` on my input_df does NOT throw an error when my class looks like this (note the nested UDF):

```
class PropertiesGetter(object):
    def __init__(self, gc):
        ...

    def add_subscription_properties(self, input_df):
        def _add_subscription_properties(self, subscription_name):
            subscription_mapping = {...}
            return subscription_mapping[subscription_name]
        udf_add_subscription_properties = udf(_add_subscription_properties, StringType())
        return input_df.withColumn("subscription_properties", 
                                   udf_add_subscription_properties("subscription_type"))

    ...
```

But it DOES throw an error 
(specifically the `Could not serialize object: Py4JError: An error occurred while calling o116.__getnewargs__. Trace:
py4j.Py4JException: Method __getnewargs__([]) does not exist..`) when it looks like this:

```
class PropertiesGetter(object):
    def __init__(self, gc):
        ...

    def _add_subscription_properties(self, subscription_name):
        subscription_mapping = {...}
        return subscription_mapping[subscription_name]

    def add_subscription_properties(self, input_df):
        udf_add_subscription_properties = udf(self._add_subscription_properties, StringType())
        return input_df.withColumn("subscription_properties", 
                                   udf_add_subscription_properties("subscription_type"))

    ...
```

Can someone please explain to me why this is? I'm struggling to understand why this makes a difference. I have a few UDFs that I'm using in this class so I want to know what a way around nesting some of these UDFs would be.

P.S. I know you do not need a UDF to create a column that applies a mapping, but just wanted to demonstrate on a simple example.